# Thymeleaf allow only ruby tag, escape other tags

Tags: thymeleaf

I want to show the `ruby` html tag in a thymeleaf template like this:

```
<h1 th:text="(${author.displayNameReading} != null) ? '<ruby><rb>' + ${author.displayName} + '</rb><rt>' + ${author.displayNameReading} + '</rt></ruby>' : ${author.displayName}" th:lang="${author.locale}">Some author name</h1>
```

If I use `th:text`, it will be escaped. It works if I use `utext`, but then I'm going to lose all the security for other html tags.

Is it possible to only allow the ruby, rt and rb tags inside `th:text`?

Answer (score 0):

Why try and stuff everything into a `th:text` attribute?  You can easily split out all that information into new tags -- which is both more readable (formatted like regular html, less string concatenation) and more secure (no need for `th:utext`).  Something like this for example:

```
<h1 th:lang="${author.locale}">
  <ruby th:if="${author.displayNameReading != null}">
    <rb th:text="${author.displayName}" />
    <rt th:text="${author.displayNameReading}" />
  </ruby>

  <span th:unless="${author.displayNameReading != null}" th:text="${author.displayName}" />
</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked fine in this case.

But what about if I have this ruby tag inside a database column or if I want to insert a string from a message bundle via `#{}`? (For example, if a message uses a `<b>` tag inside.

Comment: Thymeleaf doesn't have any support for whitelisting tags.  If you want that, you'll have to find another library that does what you want. (Presumably, you could do what you want with [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.html), but I recommend staying away from `th:utext`.)